# variable not writable in inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, variables, firebug

First I have declared a global variable and set it to 0.
In the inner function I want to set the var to another value, but my output won't set in the (global)outer var, it will be set just as a local var. My other problem is the order in which I get the output.

Output:
third0
first0
second3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    state = 0;
    $('#btnlogin').click(function() {
        $.post("php/redirect.php", {
            Username : $('#qi').attr('value'),
            Password : $('#password').attr('value')
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('first'+state);
            state = 3;
            console.log('second'+state);
        });
        console.log('third'+state);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well the order of the output is correct, considering the asynchronous ajax task. Could you explain further about the first problem (or is it related to this issue)?

Comment: @F.Calderan is correct, the order is correct - what order were you expecting?

Comment: yes now I understand, but behind that is my real problem ;) please take a look at my other comment on the next answer. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `console.log('third'+state);` is outside `$.post` (AJAX) call and calls faster than ajax response.

Seems that you misunderstood that AJAX is **asynchronous**.

Comment: oh, yes I forgot^^ I want that the click returns  true or false depending on the return of the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that the inner function on the `$.post` call will be run first when the post call returns from the server.

So you program flow will go like this when the button is clicked:

`$.post("php/redirect.php",` this will call the redirect.php method on the server side, and the up the following function to be called when the call is complete:

```
function(data) {
  console.log('first'+state);
  state = 3;
  console.log('second'+state);
}
```

Then the function continues and runs the following code:

```
console.log('third'+state);
```

At this point, state is still 0, so the output is `third0`.

Then the ajax call completes, and calls you function above, and thereby prints the following:

```
first0
second3
```

You problem is simply expecting the lines in your method, including the function you define inside to be run in the same order they appear in your script.

Comment: ok, thanks now I got it ;) but my real problem behind that is that I want to return true or false from the click handler depending on the output form the ajax request. The var problem results in my miss understandg of ajax^^

Answer (score 0):

The output is really simple to explain:

After the document has loaded you start by binding a click handler to some button. The click handler works in the following way:

- Starting an *asynchronous* AJAX call
- logging out `'third'+state`

At that point state is 0, so the first output is `third0`.

After some time the AJAX request succeded and you got your answer. When getting the answer you log `'first'+state`. With `state` still being `0` you get the output `first0`.

Afterwards you change the value of `state` to three and to the third output, which gets you the `second3`.

So to understand the behaviour you should familiarize yourself with the asynchronous version of AJAX or change the request to a synchronous style. The later is quite bad, as it would render your page unaccessible while the request is still running.